# Moving and renaming files, keeping extension but include sub directories in batch file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, subdirectory

Forgive me if this is nor the place to ask these questions, I am new to batch and scripts and a bit new to these kind of posts...

I have a folder that will receive files and folders, I want to run a script that looks at the directory and renames all files in each subfolder numerically, and moves them if possible.

For example I have something that looks like the following

```
Recieved_File_Folder
     |_folder1
     | |_file1.txt
     | |_file2.bmp
     |_folder2
     | |_file4.exe
     | |_file5.bmp
     |__file9.txt
     |__file10.jpg
```

I would like to be able to look in every directory and move it to something like this, keeping in mind the names of the files will be random and I want to keep the extension intact also.

```
Renamed_Folder
    |_folder1
    | |_1.txt
    | |_2.bmp
    |_folder2
    | |_1.exe
    | |_2.bmp
    |__1.txt
    |__2.jpg
```

I have spent alot of time on this and am not doing too well with it, any help would be very greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little script should do the trick:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /B /S /A:D') DO (

   SET /A FILE_COUNTER=1

   FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%B IN ('DIR /B /A:-D "%%A"') DO (
      CALL :RENAME "%%A%%B" !FILE_COUNTER!
      SET /A FILE_COUNTER=FILE_COUNTER+1
   )   
)   

ENDLOCAL    
GOTO :EOF    

:RENAME

SET OLD_PATH="%~f1"
SET NEW_FILE_NAME="%2%~x1"
REN %OLD_NAME% %NEW_NAME%    
GOTO :EOF
```

***Use it with care as the script will not ask for confirmation, so watch out where you start it from!***

**How does it work:**

- the first `FOR`-loop lists all sub directories recursively, starting with the current directory (using `DIR /B /S /A:D`) and passes the full path to the loop body via the variable `%%A`
- in the first loops body a variable `FILE_COUNTER` is set to the value of `1`
- the second (inner) `FOR`-loop lists all files in the directory passed in by the outer loop (using `DIR /B /A:-D "%%A"`) and passes the file's full path to its body via the variable `%%B`
- in the inner loop body the sub routine `:RENAME` is called with the full file name the current `FILE_COUNTER` value as its parameters
- the `:RENAME` sub routine uses its parameters to form the new file name and issues a rename command `REN`
- after the sub routine returns, the current `FILE_COUNTER` value is increased by one (`SET /A FILE_COUNTER=FILE_COUNTER+1`)

Comment: Frank,

Thanks so much for this! I did not use the exact code you have written though I used the most part of it and it has helped alot!

Very useful, thank you so much for taking the time to write this up for me, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think an answer solves your problem or is useful to you, it is a good habbit to accept it (mark the chekbox below the title).