# How can I change file extension and move a file to certain directory in one batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having problems trying to rename and move a single file once dragged over my batch file.

I have looked at four very similar posts and none being any help to me:

> 1. [How to rename and move files to new directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135367/how-to-rename-and-move-files-to-new-directory)
> 2. [Windows Script to Rename and move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255997/windows-script-to-rename-and-move-files)
> 3. [.bat file to rename and move files with prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069708/bat-file-to-rename-and-move-files-with-prompt)
> 4. [Moving and renaming files, keeping extension but include sub directories in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938899/moving-and-renaming-files-keeping-extension-but-include-sub-directories-in-batc)

The 4th example was closest to what I am trying to accomplish, but renames files randomly and copies them to multiple directories. All I want to be able to do is drag a file to a .bat script change the extension and move it to a certain directory.

I was trying to combine these two codes to rename and then move the files to a specific directory. But I am having trouble doing so as I am not quite sure to do so.

```
@echo off
set /p var=Move To:
%var%
cls
move %1 "%var%"
pause
```

with

```
@echo off
set /p var=File Name:
%var%
cls
set /p var2=File Type:
%var2%
Rename %1 "%var%.%var2%
```

Comment: So ... what's your question? What code do you have? What problems is it having?

Comment: I was trying to combine these two codes to rename and then move the files to a specific directory but I am having trouble doing so as I am not quite sure to do so.
    
> `@echo off
set /p var=Move To:%var%
cls
move %1 "%var%"
pause`    
    
> `@echo off 
set /p var=File Name:%var% 
cls set /p var2=File Type:%var2% 
Rename %1 "%var%.%var2%`

Comment: It would be better if you add that comment to your original question. Always try to add as much details as possible from the start so that we can understand your issue faster and formulate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing like the code you've been looking at but:

```
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "%~1" Exit/B
If Exist "%~1\" Exit/B
If Not Exist "A:\Certain Directory\%~n1.ext" Move "%~1" "A:\Certain Directory\%~n1.ext"
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving a file to another folder with changing file extension can be also done with

- selecting the file and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (Copy),
- going to the target folder and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> (Paste)
- pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> for starting renaming the file,
- changing file extension and pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

Or alternatively

- select the file and click on **Move to** command of *Windows Explorer*,
- select the destination folder in opened window and click on button **Move**,
- navigate to the destination folder and
- change the file extension there with <kbd>F2</kbd>, modifing file extension and pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

And most useful for such a task would be the usage of a file manager like *Total Commander*  which supports changing the file extension while moving the selected file(s) from left to right or right to left folder pane.

However, here is a batch script which you might use and contains already some extensions to detect some possible mistakes which can always occur when a user has to enter a path and a file extension manually. It can be still enhanced with more error checks.

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
rem Is the batch file called without an argument/parameter?
if "%~1" == "" (
    echo Call %~nx0 always with name of a file with full path.
    echo.
    echo For example:
    echo.
    echo %~nx0 "C:\Path to folder\with file to\move with new extension.txt"
    echo.
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

if not exist "%~1" (
    echo Error: There is no file
    echo.
    echo %~1
    echo.
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

if exist "%~1\" (
    echo Error: The argument
    echo.
    echo %~1
    echo.
    echo specifies a directory and not a file.
    echo.
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Preparing for moving the file
echo.
echo %~1
echo.
set "TargetFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
echo Please specify the target folder.
echo.
echo Default target is: %TargetFolder%
echo.
set /P "TargetFolder=Move to: "
echo.

rem Replace all / by \ in target folder path.
set "TargetFolder=!TargetFolder:/=\!"

rem If the target folder path ends with a backslash, remove the backslash.
if "!TargetFolder:~-1!" == "\" set "TargetFolder=!TargetFolder:~0,-1!"

rem Does the target folder really exist?
if not exist "!TargetFolder!\" (
    echo Error: The target folder
    echo.
    echo !TargetFolder!
    echo.
    echo does not exist.
    echo.
    endlocal
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

set "NewExtension=txt"
echo.
echo Please specify the new file extension.
echo.
echo Default file extension is: %NewExtension%
echo.
set /P "NewExtension=New extension: "
echo.

rem If the new file extension starts with a point, remove the point.
if "!NewExtension:~0,1" == "." set "NewExtension=!NewExtension:~1!"

rem Windows interprets everything up to last point as file name and
rem everything from last point to end of name of file as file extension.
rem On *nix systems it is common that hidden files don't have a file
rem extension and start with a point (for hiding the file). To copy such
rem files with unusual file name on Windows like .htaccess also correct,
rem it is necessary to interpret the file extension as file name if the
rem file starts with a point and has no file extension.

if not "%~n1" == "" (
    set "NewNameOfFile=%~n1.!NewExtension!"
) else (
    set "NewNameOfFile=%~x1.!NewExtension!"
)

echo.
move /-Y "%~1" "!TargetFolder!\!NewNameOfFile!"
if errorlevel 1 (
    endlocal
    echo.
    pause
) else (
    endlocal
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: *"I do not really understand what should be the benefit"* - ever heard of task automation?

Comment: What? Automation is normally built with scripts, whether it's perl, bash, windows batch or any other relevant language. Nobody forces to enter the path manually each time, it can be provided as input from another batch file output, for example

Comment: Yes, I have read it. He asks about a very specific thing, which may or may not be part of something bigger. It can be just a simplified demonstrative example that allows to omit unnecessary details as well. And in any case it's more than reasonable to assume that an average user (especially someone that wants to write batch script) would know how to handle such a basic task as moving and renaming files with Windows GUI

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername If FleetSakes would have written that any file dragged & dropped on batch file should be moved to `C:\Temp` with keeping file name, but changing file extension to `bak` and overwrite an existing file with same name and extension in `C:\Temp`, I would have written a different batch code and would understand that this script helps to automate file movements. But I can't read this in question nor in code provided by FleetSakes. Perhaps you interpret the given information by FleetSakes different than I. However, comments should not be used for a discussion about what is meant.